# LyX: insert minipage with 100% line width

Tags: lyx, minipage

I defined the following command sequence in my toolbar:

```
Item "Insert Minipage" "command-sequence box-insert Frameless; inset-modify width \"100line%\""
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. `lyx -dbg action` tells me:

```
   cmd:  action: 172 [command-sequence]  arg: 'box-insert Frameless; inset-modify width "100line%"' x: 0 y: 0
   cmd:  action: 233 [box-insert]  arg: 'Frameless' x: 0 y: 0
   cmd:  action: 226 [inset-modify]  arg: 'width "100line%"' x: 0 y: 0
>> action inset-modify [inset-modify] is disabled at this location  <<< SEE HERE
   verbose dispatch msg (command-sequence box-insert Frameless; inset-modify width "100line%")
```

What am i doing wrong?

After `box-insert Frameless`, the cursor is placed inside the minipage inset. If not there, where actually is `inset-modify` allowed?

Comment: I think `inset-modify` should be used just in front of the inset. Try adding a `char-backward` right after inserting. Does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inset-modify` should be used just in front of the inset. Thus, the command should be:

```
Item "Insert Minipage" "command-sequence box-insert Frameless; char-backward; inset-modify width \"100line%\""
```

How did I know that `inset-modify` should be used in front of the inset rather than inside it (which I agree is more intuitive)? Well, if you use the GUI and create a box (Insert > Box > Frameless), then, no matter where your cursor is, if you right click on the box and go to "Settings..." the cursor is placed just before the box.